# How to get a relative path in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do you calculate a relative path in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include an image or a script or any other file this is the code:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 14):

also, if you want the relative path inside your controller, you can use:

```
string pathName = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(string.Format(@"~/images/PhotoAlbum/{0}/", propertyId));
```

or:

```
string pathName = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(string.Format(@"~/images/PhotoAlbum/{0}/", propertyId));
```

depending on your need..

hope this helps.